# Get percentage free space on database volumes

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am currently using SQL Server 2005 and (undocumented I believe) master..xp_fixeddrives to get free space on my database volumes as part of my monitoring.

However, this only gives me an absolute number of MB free. What I really need is **percentage** free.

Is there another way in SQL Server 2005 to get this?  If not, is there some other light-weight way to get it?  If I can, I want to avoid installing a Java JRE, or Perl, or Python on my database server. Perhaps vbscript, or a small Windows executable on the file system?

Yes, I know I can Google this, and I have.  It looks like there are a few ways to accomplish it, and I'm curious how my DBA brethren have handled this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't know why you need to do this from within SQL Server. You can get this as often as you want and fairly straightforward using PowerShell, or C#, or even VBScript in a scheduled task of some kind, and then have that program update a table if you really need this stored in the database (and frequency would be dictated by how volatile your disks are and how current you need the data to be). I recommend against shelling out to the OS to collect this information while an end user is waiting.

That said, in SQL Server 2012 (and 2008 R2 SP1+) there is a new DMV called [`sys.dm_os_volume_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223223.aspx). This DMV has total size and available size so you can perform any resulting calculations from there. I haven't tested how current this data is - it may be seconds behind or more.

Comment: [Tara Kizer](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2007/12/18/60435.aspx) put out a CLR script that can also provide this info that reads from perfmon.  It's advantage over xp_fixeddrives is it also reads mountpoints.  We currently use this.